# How to generate random unique static id in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am prototyping a project that requires a unique id for each functions. here is an example.

```js
function Example(name, uuid) {
    ...
}

function start() {
    Example("Jeeva", 1)
    if (...) {
        Example("Peter", 2)
    }
    Example("June", 3)
}
```

As you can see the `start` function may called multiple times. but I want the `id` to be same. the `id` doesn't have to be a number it could be anything but has to unique to that function call.

I tried to store the ids in a list outside the `start` function and adding the `id` on first call and `shifting` them on other calls. But the issues is inside the `if` statement the function might not be executed. so after the first call if the condition changes then `Example` function will be called and shifting the id will return fails.

Can anyone point me in the right direction or is it impossible in this case?

**Edit**

OK, let me tell you why do I want this functionality. Simply put I am trying jetpack compose. If you don't know how jetpack compose works. It's a declarative UI framework. It updates (recompose) it's UI on state changes.

I am not doing this project for production, just to learn (out of curiosity).

here is an example that I am testing right now.

```js
import { Compose } from "../src/core/Compose"
import { Text } from "../src/composable/Text"

const App = scope => {
    let text = scope.stateOf("hello", 1)

    Text({ 
        text: text.value
    }, scope, 1)

    if (text.value === "hello, world") {
        Text({ text: "Hi" }, scope, 2)
    }

    if (text.value == "hello") {
        setTimeout(() => text.value = "hello, world" , 2000)
    }
}

new Compose("#app").mount(App)
```

As you can see I am passing unique numbers at the end of each composables and state. this allows me to find them on recomposition.

Comment: Can't say I understood the question, can you add some use cases/examples (and possibly, reasons to why do you need it)

Comment: But Can Id depend of first parameter of Example function ?

Comment: @Federkun I added some more explaination about this curious problem :D

Comment: @Jeeva that Edit has dramatically changed the requirements/intentions of the question and my posted answer is no longer relevant.

Comment: @ema no it can be any random string or int, but has to be unique to that function call. and I have to pass the same id on multiple call of start method